# c# Объясните почему меняется знак ":" на знак "." при форматировании строки

Tags: c#, .net, строки, format

Код такой

```cs
string strFilter = $" > '{lastupdated:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}'";
```

Если я его выведу на печать в консоль, то получаю вот это

```
> '2023-02-16 10.06'
```

Строка используется для доступа к специфичному СДК, поэтому сохранить двоеточие я обязан. Как это сделать?

Сразу скажу, что при обрезании значения я получаю нужные данные только для даты, но они не столько детализированы по времени как мне нужно.

##### UPDATE

Мои предположения не подтвердились. В любом месте данного проекта, форматирование даты приводит к результату с точкой.

Сначала думал, что логгер не верно выводит. Вывел просто в консоль. Все одно. Двоеточие меняется на точку.

Форматы которые перебрал:

1. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss.fff` -> вывод '2023-02-17 13.02.47.000'
2. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM` -> вывод '2023-02-17 13.02'
3. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss` -> вывод '2023-02-17 13.02.47'

Comment: ты уверен что это актуальный вывод, а не с прошлых попыток? Приведенный код работает как и ожидается

Comment: @Grundy перепроверил, дейстивтельно так, потому что при запросе я получаю фатальную ошибку от СДК и сразу вывожу в лог строку. То есть у меня ошибка и следом логом содержание строки

Comment: попробуй просто сделать такую строку и вывести в консоль, без твоего сдк

Comment: @Grundy таки да, так все работает. Логгер что ли форматирует без моего ведома... Не пойму, поскольку строка то формируется до запроса. Значит надо подбирать формат, который скушает СДК

Comment: @Dmitry, а правила CultureInfo ты пробовал задавать? Может поможет?

Comment: @Grundy я попробовал в нескольких частях всего проекта с выводом просто строки без всего в консоль. Двоеточие меняется на точку.

Comment: @Dmitry, но выше ты писал что выводит `:`. Чем отличаются эти варианты?

Comment: [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) - здесь описано, что символ `:` является не литералом, а спецификатором формата. И выводимый символ будет меняться в зависимости от культуры. Поэтому нужно либо задать текущую культуру потока, либо указать культуру при вызове метода форматирования, либо обернуть `:` в апострофы - тогда это будет считаться литералом.

Comment: @Grundy я открыл новый проект и попробовал в нем, там все сработало. А после перешел в проект существующий и попробовал в разных частях решения, здесь отображается точка.

Comment: @Dmitry, интересно. Надо смотреть чем отличаются проекты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте обернуть `:` в апострофы:

```
string strFilter = $" > '{lastupdated:yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm}'";
```

[Про разделитель между временем](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#timeSeparator)

Comment: Да, этот вариант сработал как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Источник проблемы не найден и я остановился в поиске. Запихнул такой костыль

```cs
string strDateTime = $" > '{lastupdated:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}'".Replace(".", ":");
```

Игры с `System.Globalization` так же не принесли результата. Создавать кастомный `CultureInfo` как описано в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#examples) не стал. Оказалось еще более громоздко.